# How to get the entity ID in a twig template

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I have a custom entity, with the template `my-custom-entity--my-entity.html.twig`.

How do I access the ID in the template? ***I can do this by implementing `hook_preprocess_entity`, but am wondering if the ID is already available in the template.***

Comment: Did you try passing the entity object as a variable and then {{ entity_object_name.id() }}?

Comment: I had just passed the ID as a variable. I guess I could pass the whole object in case I need other properties from it. I was mainly asking if the ID or the entity object is already available to the templates natively.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the full object to a twig variable, so

```
$vars['myentity'] = $my_entity;
```

and then access with

```
{{ myentity.id }}
```

A bit more elegant is to implement hook_theme:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MODULENAME_theme() {
  return [
    'customentity' => [
      'render element' => 'elements',
    ],
  ];
}
```

and a preprocess function to expose it to twigs customentity and maybe content variables:

```
function template_preprocess_customentity(&$variables) {
  $variables['customentity'] = $variables['elements']['#node'];

  // Helpful $content variable for templates.
  $variables += ['content' => []];
  foreach (Element::children($variables['elements']) as $key) {
    $variables['content'][$key] = $variables['elements'][$key];
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that would need to be `{{ myentity.id() }}`. Thanks for the answer. I had done something similar to this. What I was really trying to figure out here is if the entity id is already exposed natively, but I am guessing it is not.

Comment: No, it isn't. Except your using a content type ;) Sometimes a custom entity is not worth the effort .. especially when it comes to make it fieldable, translateable or revisionable.